# Why do I get an error when I insert something like ';' or '&' in a Plindrome program?

Tags: c

Why do I get an error when I insert something like ';' or '&' in a Palindrome program?

I'd like to create a Palindrome program that automatically excludes special symbols.
eg:

mad!am -> The Palindrome is correct.
But it doesn't work. It only works when I put madam, but when I put mad!am, it gives an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 100

typedef char element;
typedef struct {
    element data[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    int top;
} StackType;


void init_stack(StackType* s)
{
    s->top = -1;
}


int is_empty(StackType* s)
{
    return (s->top == -1);
}

int is_full(StackType* s)
{
    return (s->top == (MAX_STACK_SIZE - 1));
}

void push(StackType* s, element item)
{
    if (is_full(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
        return;
    }
    else s->data[++(s->top)] = item;
}

element pop(StackType* s)
{
    if (is_empty(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else return s->data[(s->top)--];
}

element peek(StackType* s)
{
    if (is_empty(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else return s->data[s->top];
}

int main(void)
{
    StackType s, a, k;
    init_stack(&s);
    init_stack(&a);
    init_stack(&k);
    int i=0;
    char input[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    printf("문자열을 입력하세요: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    int length = strlen(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if ('a' <= input[i] && input[i] <= 'z') {
            push(&s, input[i]);
            push(&a, input[i]);
        }
        else if ('A' <= input[i] && input[i] <= 'Z') {
            push(&s, input[i] - ('A' - 'a'));
            push(&a, input[i] - ('A' - 'a'));
        }
        

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        push(&k, pop(&s));
    }
    while (k.data[MAX_STACK_SIZE]!=NULL) {
            
        if (peek(&a) != peek(&k))
        {
            printf("not palindrome \n");
            break;
            return 0;
        }
        pop(&k);
        pop(&a);
        printf("palindrome ok!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "it gives an error" mean? Which error and where?

Comment: You push fewer then `length` characters unto `a` and `s` when the input includes `!`, so the loop where you pop from `s` shouldn't have `length` iterations.

Comment: there was a issue with string length please check out my answer and try the code.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid constructs like `if ('a' <= input[i] && input[i] <= 'z')`. That's just makes a mess. In your case, just use `isalpha()`.

But the problem lies in the for loop after you have read all the characters. Since you're skipping characters you cannot use `length` again. Do these changes:

```
int length = strlen(input);
int no_letters=0; 
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (isalpha(input[i])) {
        push(&s, input[i]);
        push(&a, input[i]);
        no_letters++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < no_letters; i++)
{
    push(&k, pop(&s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a small bug with length.. You should ignore counting string length for those element which should not be counted.. Here I have corrected the code with comment , compiled and run.. It is working correct now...

Please try below code... I have added comment what I added..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 100

typedef char element;
typedef struct {
element data[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    int top;
} StackType;


void init_stack(StackType* s)
{
   s->top = -1;
}


int is_empty(StackType* s)
 {
    return (s->top == -1);
 }

 int is_full(StackType* s)
 {
     return (s->top == (MAX_STACK_SIZE - 1));
  }

 void push(StackType* s, element item)
 {
       if (is_full(s)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
           return;
       }
 else s->data[++(s->top)] = item;
 }

 element pop(StackType* s) 
 {
    if (is_empty(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
        exit(1);
      }
  else return s->data[(s->top)--];
  }

  element peek(StackType* s)
  {
       if (is_empty(s)) {
           fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
          exit(1);
       }
   else return s->data[s->top];
  }

 int main(void)
 {
      StackType s, a, k;
      init_stack(&s);
      init_stack(&a);
      init_stack(&k);
      int i=0;
      char input[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
      printf("문자열을 입력하세요: ");
      scanf("%s", input);
      int length = strlen(input);

     int len=0;  // added

     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     if ('a' <= input[i] && input[i] <= 'z') {
        push(&s, input[i]);
        push(&a, input[i]);

        len++;   //counting length for valid characters
     }
     else if ('A' <= input[i] && input[i] <= 'Z') {
        push(&s, input[i] - ('A' - 'a'));
        push(&a, input[i] - ('A' - 'a'));

       len++;  //counting length for valid characters only
        }
    

     } 
     for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
     {
       push(&k, pop(&s));
     }
    while (k.data[MAX_STACK_SIZE]!=NULL) {
        
        if (peek(&a) != peek(&k))
        {
           printf("not palindrome \n");
           break;
           return 0;
        }
       pop(&k);
       pop(&a);
      printf("palindrome ok!\n");
   }

  return 0;
 }
```